# OctoberCMS translate YAML default texts

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

As an example I have a translatable model:

```php
class Settings extends Model {
    public $implement = [
        'System.Behaviors.SettingsModel',
        'RainLab.Translate.Behaviors.TranslatableModel'
    ];

    public $settingsCode = 'zollerboy_customtheme_settings';
    public $settingsFields = 'fields.yaml';

    public $translatable = [
        'site_name',
        //I have a lot more here
    ];
}
```

My `fields.yaml` looks like this:

```yaml
tabs:
    fields:
        site_name:
            tab: Info
            label: Website Name
            type: text

        # And so on ...
```

Is it possible, that I give the field `site_name` a default value for each language?

I tried it with

```yaml
default: name.plugin::lang.settings.default.site_name
```

but that seems to just work with labels but not with default values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the default option does not work with translations, but you can display this field through of the widget form, getting the default value in the visualization method.

```
public function render() {
    $value= Lang::get('name.plugin::lang.settings.default.site_name');
    return $this->makePartial('site_name', ['value' => $value, 'name' => 
    'site_name']);
}
```

Register form widgets by overriding the registerFormWidgets method inside the Plugin registration class.

```
public function registerFormWidgets() {
    return [
          'Name\Plugin\FormWidgets\SiteName' => 'site_name'

    ];
}
```

Example fields.yaml:

```
tabs:
fields:
    site_name:
        tab: Info
        label: Website Name
        type: site_name

    # And so on ...
```

Comment: But this does override the values, that are different then the default value, right?

Comment: This field output is similar to your example above only through your widget. Here $value is the default

Comment: In the visualization method can add a condition to not override the default value.

Comment: Everything works for me, maybe we are talking about different things. I uploaded a test plugin on github.com - https://github.com/Alleksk/test-plugin